# Why doesn't my new gallery show up on my facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-photos

I've uploaded a bunch of photos to a new gallery on my Facebook page. However, this gallery does not show up in the timeline - I need to share the link manually which results in me not being able to select the "main" image for example.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when adding a date/time before posting the initial gallery. There's a "hide in feed" checkbox but even if it's unchecked it won't show up in the page's feed/timeline. It does not matter if a time is specified manually or if you let FB take the information from the exif tags.

Unfortunately there is no way to solve this issue except by deleting the gallery and uploading the images again; this time without adding date/time information.